# Running the same event handler for two different events on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a form with a field and a submit button.

I want the same function to run when either action (click or change) occurs.

Currently I have it set up this way :

```
$("#btn-search").click(function() {
    $(".forminput").change();
});

$(".forminput").change(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

However, this seems to fire the //do stuff part multiple times. Is there a better way to do it, or is the problem likely elsewhere?

Comment: Are you changing any of the values in the .change function?  I could see that maybe causing some sort of repeated change loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be a better approach and should prevent your code from firing multiple times.

```
function doStuff(e) { 
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // do stuff
}
$('.forminput').on('change', doStuff);
$('#btn-search').on('click', doStuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your event handler doesn't require being in the context of `.forminput` (i.e. it doesn't use `$(this)` at all), then you can create one function to use for both of them:

```
function clickChangeHandler(){
    // do stuff
}

$("#btn-search").click(clickChangeHandler);
$(".forminput").change(clickChangeHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function which will be called for the events you want. Example:

```
$('#one').click(foo);
$('#two').change(foo);

function foo(){
    // do stuff... this and $(this) are also usable.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one eventHandler for both cases.
In case if you need to distinguish events you can use event argument to handle them differently

```
function eventHandler (event) {}

$("#btn-search").click(eventHandler);

$(".forminput").change(eventHandler);
```